# Me and my generating functions - dice, probability (Introductory)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, generating-functions

**"Five regular dice are rolled. What is the probability that the sum of the five numbers shown is equal to 14?"**

*This problem is not specifically ment to be solved with a generating function, but since I've just read about generating functions (the basics) I figured that I should try anyways, and that only got me so far...*

**My approach using Generating functions:**

Each die can give the numbers $1$-$6$, and we have $5$ dice which gives our generating function:

$G(x)=$ ($x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6$)$^5=x^5$($1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5$)$^5$

Next, we are going to utilize the expression whose Taylor Expansion yields $(1,x,x^2,x^3,...)$, which is $(1-x)^{-1}$, and rewrite our generating function as if we were dealing with this infinite series instead:

$G(x) = x^5(1-x)^{-5}$

*This i reckon is done primarily so that we handle binomials instead of series, for which we have powerful formulas for finding coefficients. We can do this because the use of Taylor Expansions "back and forth" do not affect the coefficients(?).*

To compute the probability we need to divide the number of ways the sum $14$ can appear, with the number of ways any sum $5$-$30$ can appear. I.e. we are going to compute:

$$\frac {[x^{14}]G(x)}{\sum_{i=5}^{30} [x^i]G(x)}.$$

By the Binomial Theorem we know the coefficent is the same as $C(n,k)a^{n-k}b^k$; for our numerator $[x^{14}]G(x)=[x^{9}](1-x)^{-5}$, we have $a = 1, b = -x, n = -5, k = 9$, so the coefficinet is:

$C(n,k)a^{n-k}b^k$$=$$C(-5,9) 1^{(-5-9)} (-1)^{-9}=-C(-5,9)=C(13,9).$

Similarly we get $\sum_{i=5}^{30} [x^i]G(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{25} C(-5,i)(-1)^{i}$ and so we should have the answer after dividing. However, when i compute the probability with the use of Wolffram alpha, I get $715/142505$ which is around $0.5$%, whereas the desired answer is approximately $7$%.

I believe that my mistake is that I have assumed the dice to be distinguishable, which they appear not to be, and so now I can't figure out how to adjust the formula so that it gives the correct answer. That is, if it is possible to formulate a "multichoose combination scenario" with generating functions. Furthermore, I am new to generating functions so it would be nice if you explained your answer thoroughly, any thoughts regarding improvements are appreciated aswell. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $[x^{14}](x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^5=540$  See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Coefficient((x%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E5%2Bx%5E6)%5E5,x%5E14) $540/6^5=.06944444444$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did at the very beginning is correct, and leads to the correct answer.

$[x^{14}](x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^5=540$
See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Coefficient((x%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E5%2Bx%5E6)%5E5,x%5E14)

Then $${540\over6^5}=.06944444444$$ is the probability.

I don't understand what you did after the first paragraph of your question.  I think you may have wanted to do something like

$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)^5=\left({1-x^6\over1-x}\right)^5=\left(1-x^6\right)^5(1-x)^{-5}$$ so that $$G(x)=x^5H(x)J(x)$$ where $H,J$ can be computed by the binomial formula.  As it is, you've replaced $G$ by some other function.

What you say at the end about the dice perhaps not being distinguishable is also confusing.  The dice *are* distinguishable, as you have assumed.  I don't know what the problem would mean if the dice weren't distinguishable. How could they show different numbers?

Comment: It is true that I replaced G with some other function and I have realized my mistake there, I wrongly assumed that it did not matter if the die could show any numbers higher than 6. I thought "in the case where one die shows 100, (or any other number) it won't matter because there is no ways of forming a sum of 14 with that large numbers under the condition that no die can be negative". BUT, the numbers 7-10 do matter, now (10,1,1,1,1) is a possibility which clearly should not exist.

Comment: @Hassebae Exactly.  Can you do it if you proceed along the lines I suggested?  That works out pretty easily.

Comment: With dice not being distinguishable, I mean that, except for the numbers that are revealed there is no telling the diffrence between the dice. In contrast to what i just said, lets say the dice are all painted in different colors, one could then distingush (5,5,2,1,1) form (1,1,2,5,5) where the one time the green die showed a 5, and the second time a 1. So my suggestion in the end of the post is: Maybe all dice look the same, then there should be no telling the difference between  (5,5,2,1,1) and (1,1,2,5,5) because the dice are identical. Have i misunderstood the use of "distinguishable"?

Comment: Even if all the dice look the same, we have to distinguish between $(1,2)$ and $(2,1).$  Otherwise, we would say that there are $21$ possibilities in rolling $2$ dice, and $3$ ways to roll $7$, so the probability of rolling $7$ is $\frac17$ instead of $\frac16.$  This is what I was getting at, but I didn't phrase it very well.  If we don't distinguish between the dice, there's no hope of getting the right probability.  Anyway, you've already identified what your true error was, so this issue doesn't matter.

Comment: I have gained some serious insight thanks to you, you can expect being tagged in future problems that i have :). Have some upvotes.